# Check Two DataGridViews if both of them are equal or not in c# windows form

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview, compare, equals

I have two datagridviews. I want to check if both of them are same or not, the columns are always the same. I just want to check if the rows are same or not.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Rows same ? Do you mean all the items? You cannot direct compare both datagridviews. You can try add datagridviews items to two arrays and compare them one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be better ways, but ...

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dgv1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
        dgv1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
        dgv1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());

        dgv1.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3);
        dgv1.Rows.Add(4, 5, 6);

        dgv2.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
        dgv2.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
        dgv2.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());

        dgv2.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3);
        dgv2.Rows.Add(4, 5, 6);

        var ar1 = string.Join(",", (from row in dgv1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                                    from cell in row.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>()
                                    select cell.Value));

        var ar2 = string.Join(",", (from row in dgv2.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                                    from cell in row.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>()
                                    select cell.Value));

        Debug.Print((ar1.Equals(ar2)).ToString());

    }
```